# Binning a column in a DataFrame into 10 percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to qcut or cut my "Amount" column into bins of 10 percentiles. Basically the describe() feature but with 0-10%, 11-20%, 21-30%, 31-40%, 41-50%, 51-60%, 61-70%, 71-80%, 81-90%, 91-100% instead.

After the binning i'd like to create a column that shows 1-10 indicating the bin that particular amount is apart of.

I've tried using this code below, however, I do not believe it's achieving what I want.

```
groups = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Amount'], 10)).size()
```

Here is my DataFrame!

```
df.shape
Out[5]: (1385, 2)

df.head(10)
Out[6]: 
   Amount         New or Repeat Customer
0  23044                    New
1  15509                    New
2   6184                    New
3   6184                    New
4   5828                    New
5   5461                    New
6   5143                    New
7   5027                    New
8   4992                    New
9   4698                 Repeat
```

Comment: Either `pd.qcut` or `pd.cut(series, series.quantile(np.arange(0,1.01,0.1))`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html):

```
# Sample data
size = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Amount': np.random.randint(5000, 20000, size),
    'CustomerType': np.random.choice(['New', 'Repeat'], size)
})

# Binning
labels = ['0% to 10%'] + [f'{i+1}% to {i+10}%' for i in range(10, 100, 10)]
df['Bin'] = pd.qcut(df['Amount'], 10, labels=labels)
```

Result:

```
   Amount CustomerType          Bin
0   15597       Repeat   61% to 70%
1   14498          New   51% to 60%
2    6373       Repeat    0% to 10%
3    9901       Repeat   21% to 30%
4   18450       Repeat  91% to 100%
5    9337       Repeat   21% to 30%
6   19310       Repeat  91% to 100%
7   11198          New   31% to 40%
8   12485          New   41% to 50%
9   11130          New   31% to 40%
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates values? I am getting an error so I passed in duplicates = 'drop' however the labels need to be one fewer.